# how read properties value from database.confid in generatoConfig my batis

Tags: java, xml, mybatis, mybatis-generator

Suppose to be in `/resourses` folder and there are two files (`database.properties` and `generatorConfig.xml`). My purpose is insert in database.properties the database properties:

```
jdbc.driverClassName="DRIVER"
jdbc.url="URL"
jdbc.username="****"
jdbc.password="****"
```

Now in my generatorConfig.xml I do:

```
    <generatorConfiguration>

         <properties resource="database.properties"></properties>
        <context id="context1">

            <jdbcConnection connectionURL="${jdbc.url}"
                driverClass="${jdbc.driverClassName}" password="${jdbc.password}"
                userId="${jdbc.user}" >

            </jdbcConnection>
....
```

But when I run the file I obtain this exception:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception getting JDBC Driver` 
It seems that It doesn't read the database.properties. Anyone can help  me?

Answer (score 0):

This should work as long as `/resources` is on the classpath of the generator.